# python padding formatting alternative?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a custom way of padding lines of text in python, I am using the escape characters "\t", but I wonder if there is an alternative.
for example

```
print('My Name is:')
print('Rambo')
print('Mambo')
```

Output:

```
.My Name is:
.....Rambo
..Mambo
```

Comment: write own `print()` and format as you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple function for yourself.

```
def p(a,b):
 print(" "*a + b)

p(1,"while")
```

This should return:`" while"`

Comment: Ingenious.... never came to my find.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
print('{:>15}'.format('My Name is:'))
```

Refer for examples:
[PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: Seems to work, but does not work, the first print works, but the next prints are awful/

Comment: change the variable '15' according to your need.. don't expect this as an exact solution
Its just an example ;)